# Raspberry Pi: Geth slow sync every time reboot

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, raspberry-pi

Since the first sync (I copy the chaindata folder from my local machine to the RPI), every time I start the RPI it takes hours to just sync 20k blocks.

I tried `geth --cache=512`, etc.

I am using WIFI and the OS is the one given in http://ethembedded.com

Comment: What version of geth are you using? Have you tried the Rust or C++ clients? They're much faster.

Comment: @TjadenHess hi. geth version 1.3.5. No i did not try parity. can I run it and copy the chaindata folder to it? or i have to sync all again?

Comment: I have been using [pre-compiled geth binary](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-ARM) in a RPI for a while now and syncing is very fast. Try that. Also, what are the RPI specs?

Comment: @variable hi. It is RPI 3. So you recommend download it again all the blockchain? or use the pre-compiled and copy the chaindata into it?